# How can I implement trait B for all types that implement trait A if both traits are implemented for references?

Tags: rust

We have two traits `A` and `B` for which

1. I can trivially implement `B` for all types that implement `A`.
2. I can trivially implement `A` for references to any type implementing `A`.
3. I can trivially implement `B` for references to any type implementing `B`.

Actually doing all three leads to a conflict, because now references to types that implement `A` would have two implementations of `B` for them. One due to the `impl<T: A> A for &T` and one transitively due to the `impl<T: A> B for T` (and then the `impl<T: B> B for &T`.

I can't remove the `impl<T: B> B for &T`, because there might be types that implement `B` but not `A`

Here's an example code exhibiting the behaviour.

```
trait A {}
trait B {}

impl<'a, T: A> A for &'a T {}
impl<T: A> B for T {}

impl<'a, T: B> B for &'a T {}
```

which results in the following error:

```
error[E0119]: conflicting implementations of trait `B` for type `&_`:
  |
  | impl<T: A> B for T {}
  | --------------------- first implementation here
  | impl<'a, T: B> B for &'a T {}
  | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ conflicting implementation for `&_`
```

Is it possible to use the Rust typesystem in a way to ensure that when there is an `impl B for &A`, we don't create one for `&B`?

Comment: This [blog post](http://smallcultfollowing.com/babysteps/blog/2016/09/24/intersection-impls/) and the [internals thread about it](https://internals.rust-lang.org/t/blog-post-intersection-impls/4129) have a lot of discussion about it.  The summary in general is "not yet", but there might be some ideas in there that might help.

Comment: @ChrisEmerson: Maybe it would be worth making this an answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There has been some [discussion on the Rust internals forum](https://internals.rust-lang.org/t/blog-post-intersection-impls/4129) on this topic, starting with [a blog post by Nicholas Matsakis](http://smallcultfollowing.com/babysteps/blog/2016/09/24/intersection-impls/) about how to handle the issue of overlapping trait implementations.

Today, (unstable) Rust has [some impl specialisation](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/blob/master/text/1210-impl-specialization.md), but that only works for strictly more specific impls of a more generic one.

So I think the answer is that there isn't a good way to do it today, but at some point in the future there's a good chance that Rust will evolve to allow expressing overlapping trait impls.